# Bucketing investments to track individual growths

Tags: investing

I'm looking to invest several small amounts of money in an investment account, as well as a continued stream of small contributions.  The total sum is maybe $3000 to start, in sizes of about $100-$300 each.  I'd like to be able to track individual contributions so I can see the sources of growth, but without needing to purchase individually, as even a $7.95 trade cost will add up too fast.  I might want to just put the $3000 into a single purchase, or maybe even two stock purchases.  Is there a system or method to do this?

So I want to end up with a list of something like this:

```
BUY $500
$100   $107    7%
$100   $107    7%
$100   $105    5%
$200   $204    2%
...
```

EDIT:
To explain better:   This is for my daughter's investment account which will be funded with small contributions like christmas or birthday money, along with a regular parental contribution probably.  I'd like to be able to track individual contributions, like "christmas 2013 from grandma", throughout its investment life.  So, if grandma gave $100 in 2013... and it was invested, sold, invested, sold, etc, how can I best track that original $100's cost basis indefinitely?

I use spreadsheets a lot but haven't figured out how to best track this way.

Answer (score 1):

Some personal finance packages can track basis cost of individual purchase lots or fractions thereof. I believe Quicken does, for example. And the mutual funds I'm invested in tell me this when I redeem shares. I can't vouch for who/what would make this visible at times other than sale; I've never had that need.

For that matter I'm not sure what value the info would have unless you're going to try to explicitly sell specific lots rather than doing FIFO or Average accounting.

Comment: Sounds like perhaps the OP wants to use this partially as an educational tool for the daughter.